# Giving error on first load

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

Having problem on first load but when i refresh the page it seems okay. Is it problem with firebase database plugin loading?
How to get rid of this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your definition of pays in wrong, try

```
pays : any[] = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need declare it like this:

```
pays : any = [];
```